# Adding a for loop to the list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

**This is the question from the Python book:**

Design a program that asks the user to enter a store's sales for each day of the week. The amounts should be stored in a list. Use a loop to calculate the total sales for the week and display the result.

**This is what I have so far in the Python code:**

```
Sunday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Sunday: "))
Monday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Monday: "))
Tuesday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Tuesday: "))
Wednsday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Wednsday: "))
Thursday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Thursday: "))
Friday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Friday: "))
Saturday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Saturday: "))

store_week_sales = [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednsday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday]

index = 0
```

**I'm not so sure on how to add the loop so that I can calulate the total sales of the week. Help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Something not directly related to the question:
You could do `sales = [int(input('Enter store sales for %s: ' % day)) for day in ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
total = 0

for store_sale in store_week_sales:
    total += store_sale

print "Total week sales: %.2f" % total
```

Python does not makes a difference between `for` and (non-existent) `foreach`, since `for` already iterates over the elements of an iterable, not over index numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to do it with a for loop, it can be done like 
heltonbiker describes. Alternatively, you can do it with the function sum.

```
sumOfList = sum(store_week_sales);
```

Since it is an exercise in for loops, this is probably not what your looking for this time, but it can be good to know for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

    total = 0.0
    daily_sales = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    index = 0

    days_of_the_week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednsday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

    for index in range(7):

        print("Enter the amount of sales for", days_of_the_week[index])
        daily_sales[index] = float(input("Enter the sales here: "))

        total += daily_sales[index]

    print("The total sales for the week is $", format(total, '.2f'), sep = ' ')

main()
```

Comment: Please add some narrative to explain what this code you dumped on us does and how/why.